# CefSharp WPF web browser is not displayed Or rendered

Tags: c#, webview, cefsharp

Am new to CefSharp 
I have created a class library project and referenced the CefSharp library to render the Web browser,  However I am facing some issues showing the web Browser. Please find the exact code

WebBrowser_test1:

```
 public partial class ChildWidget : Window
    {
        public CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser webView;
        public Widget()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CefSharp.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings();
            settings.PackLoadingDisabled = true;
            if (CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings))
            {
                webView = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
                main_grid.Children.Add(webView);
                webView.Address = "http://www.google.co.uk";
            }
        }
    }
```

and I am referencing this library (dll) in another project

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Button newbutton = new Button();
            newbutton.Width = 50;
            main_grid.Children.Add(newbutton);
            newbutton.Click += ButtonClick;
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Webbrowser_test1.ChildWidget childWidget = new Widget();
                childWidget.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
          }
```

Now on the Button click I will open the (WebBrowser_test1) child widget in which I will show the web browser .. when the window opens it is showing blank.

Please let me know if I missing anything

Answer (score 9):

Subscribe to `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` after creating a `ChromiumWebBrowser`.  Then once the browser is initialized you can call `Load` and your control will be displayed.

```
...
    _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
    mainGrid.Children.Add(_browser);
    _browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;
...

void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        _browser.Load("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of the first three potential issues. But it's hard to tell what the real issue is from your code alone as it strays off a bit from the official examples

1. Move `Cef.Initialize()` to your `MainWindow` constructor. It should only be called once to launch the `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe` renderer process.
2. See my answer to [CefSharp 3 always failing Cef.Initialize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566678/cefsharp-3-always-failing-cef-initialize) for a few things to check regarding binaries and their placement. *Really, the recommended approach is to start having the WPF example in the CefSharp.MinimalExample repo running first* and then adjust to your use case from there.
3. I'm not sure a `ChromiumWebBrowser()` without explicitly setting a width and height works. A 0x0 window might not receive any rendered content. I haven't tried with recent code.

Comment: Hi there @Jornh, I am having a similar problem but when I run the aplication on visual studio it works perfectly but when I publish, it keeps loading a blank page instead of the regular UI. I have also looked about how to publish a click once application, but it seems to be correct. Do you have any tips for me? ive beeing struggling with this a few day now.

Comment: Sorry it’s been a few years since I’ve worked with CefSharp. 
Only thing I can suggest is the usual stuff to maybe look for missing DLLs in your deployment and usual stuff like errors if you can get a debugger attached.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing

```
webView.Address = "http://www.google.co.uk";
```

with

```
webView.Load("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried with  webView.Load("http://www.google.co.uk"); But still I could not get this done.

Comment: Well this in general absolutely works, and cefsharp is wonderful, so I think it's the slightly exotic 'control' in a 'control' usage you're going for.

My instinct says it's a lifetime issue. I'd advise against calling Load (as you say you're now calling) in the control constructor. You need to let CEF load the dll ( ~20Mb ) into memory first and intialise.

There's an IsBrowserInitialised event that can help there. 

I'd also advise creating a new project, without using controls, that simply loads and CEFSharp and displays a webpage to familiarize yourself with cef.

Answer (score 0):

Like jornh mentions, you may have to explicitly set the height and width of the `ChromiumWebBrowser`. If you don't know the exact size, setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` (to fill the parent container) will probably also work.

Have you checked if the `Cef.Initialize()` actually returns `true`? You could be missing some files, and CefSharp doesn't always give clear error messages when this is the case.